# .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows 7 w SP1 not showing on Window Features List

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell, plugins, .net-framework

I've successfully installed *.NET Framework 4.5.2* on a *Windows 7 w SP1* laptop, in preparation for upgrading to Office 2013 Professional.  Installation of Office 2013 still saying I need *Internet Information Services (IIS) 7.0*.  Went into Window features to turn it on.  Only still showing *.NET Framework 3.5.1*, and *IIS 6*. Install is also saying I'm missing *Window Powershell V3*.  How do I get it to switch to *.NET Framework 4.5.2* and *IIS 7.0*? Note: *.NET Framework 3.5.1* is not showing on the program list.

Comment: .NET 4.5.2 isn't going to show up on the Windows Feature list because its not a feature of Windows 7 only .NET Framework 3.5.1 was.  IIS 7.5 should be there, it not being there, is a seperate issue

Comment: @Ramhound: It depends on MS though, doesn't it? If they want then the .NET 4.5.2 installer can very well update the Windows Features list. After all, IE does it and if you have IE 9/10/11 installed then that's what shows up in the list instead of IE 8.

Comment: @Karan - I don't believe thats the case with .NET Framework 4.5.2 though.  It might be possible to streamline it into your .WIM though.

Comment: @Ramhound: No, I don't think it is, but I was just responding to your comment that it doesn't show up "because its not a feature of Windows 7". Like I said, newer features can be added to the list as IE shows. Anyway now the question is why the OP is missing certain entries. Some sort of corruption perhaps? Do you know where the entries are pulled from? The Windows Features dialog takes some time to populate the list, so it must be reading registry entries or enumerating files or something, which is where the answer to this question might lie.

Comment: @Karan - If a Windows Feature is missing, and cannot be installed, then its not located in the WinSxS directory.  So one can either add it back manually or use the installer at least for .NET Framework 4.5.2 and Powershell 3.0.  I want some progress on that front before I determine how to get IIS which will take at least 2 hours of research on my part :$

Comment: @JBaldes: Have you tried running `sfc /scannow` from an admin command prompt already?

Comment: Would be nice to know if [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-install-iis-on-windows-vista/) is what the user sees.  If its not then [DISM](http://serverfault.com/questions/222644/windows-7-equivalent-of-add-windowsfeature) can be used to add the features back

Comment: Its also possible due to the version of [Windows 7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753473.aspx) the author is using IIS simply cannot be installed.  I really don't know I have a dozen questions to be answers, and after those are answered, a dozen more.