# Microsoft .NET framework 4.5.x is installed but not an option in Turn Windows Features On/Off

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

I had been running .NET framework version 3.5, Windows 7 "Enterprise" with Service Pack 1 (kb976932) emulated in VMWare Fusion on Mac OSX, but I need to update for a particular software.

I've successfully installed version 4.5.2 -- it shows up in Add/Remove Programs, but it doesn't seem to be making the jump to the menu in Turn Windows Features On/Off (which still offers me 3.5.1).  The .NET framework repair utility is perfectly happy to (pretend to repair it), but nothing changes after rebooting.

I've read the inconclusive discussion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/913913/net-framework-4-5-2-on-windows-7-w-sp1-not-showing-on-window-features-list), but they lost me at IIS (not a regular windows user).

Comment: Windows 7 ships with .NET 4, it cannot be removed or disabled. .NET 3.5 is the legacy runtime for previous versions of .NET and is optional. So what's the problem. You updated, but did you try running whatever software you're trying to run since then? /edit: Scratch that, it didn't ship with 4.0. But whatever. Nothing out of the ordinary here.

Comment: It's not suppose to appear in the Windows Feature because 4.5.2 isn't a Windows 7 feature only 3.5 is likewise on 8 it would be a feature and on 10 4.6.x is a feature

Comment: @DanielB -- Huh, who knew?  I assumed the procedure would be the same as for 3.5 (have to actually enable it).  I had tried to install my software and failed, but that may have been before the repairs.  It's flying through its installation at this very moment.  Thanks!

Comment: @DanielB no it comes with 3.5, the 4 can be removed via program & features->installed programs